# Allowing nagios plugin check_dhcp to work without setuid root

Tags: linux, nagios, permissions, suid

Nagios has a plugin, [`check_dhcp`](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/doc/man/check_dhcp.html), that does exactly what you'd think. It's [widely suggested](https://www.rubysecurity.org/nagios_dhcp-monitoring) to install it setuid root, because it [uses `SO_BINDTODEVICE`](https://github.com/nagios-plugins/nagios-plugins/blob/master/plugins-root/check_dhcp.c#L774), which usually only root can do. Of course a similar thing can be accomplished with `sudo` as well, but it remains that `check_dhcp` would be executing with the whole of root privileges when it doesn't need them.

Unfortunately, `check_dhcp` seems to be rather stupidly written for this usage, and does not make any attempt to drop root privileges after doing what it needs to do. This leads to at least one known [security problem](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/33387/), but just [generally is bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_authority) and I'd like to not do it.

So I'm wondering, is there some way I can enable `check_dhcp` to do its necessary network interface frobbing, without granting it outright all root privileges? Perhaps something with capabilities, SELinux, AppArmor, or similar? Looking for a Linux solution -- Ubuntu 14.04 in particular.

Comment: Why wouldn't sudo work?

Comment: @EEAA because just like setuid, it grants the process root privileges outright. `sudo` is *somewhat* better in that I can restrict which users can rootify the process, but the fact remains that most of `check_dhcp` will execute with root privileges when in fact it has no need for them after it has applied `SO_BINDTODEVICE` to the socket. sudo is also somewhat worse in that I have to modify the nagios configuration to invoke the plugin via sudo, and configure sudo in the first place. All possible for sure, but somewhat inconvenient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`SO_BINDTODEVICE` requires `CAP_NET_RAW`. `check_dhcp` also wants to bind to port 68, which requires `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`. See [capabilities(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) for detailed descriptions of the available capabilities.

These two capabilities can be granted to the executable with [`setcap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html), like this:

```
setcap 'cap_net_raw,cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_dhcp
```

This should allow any user to run `check_dhcp` successfully, without possibly (if they can exploit `check_dhcp`) giving them full root privileges.

The plugin will still (rather stupidly) emit a warning:

```
$ ./check_dhcp 
Warning: This plugin must be either run as root or setuid root.
To run as root, you can use a tool like sudo.
To set the setuid permissions, use the command:
    chmod u+s yourpluginfile
OK: Received 2 DHCPOFFER(s), max lease time = 259200 sec.
```

To address this, you could:

- Ignore it. Nagios will still look at the exit status to get the plugin state.
- Remove the [call to `np_warn_if_not_root`](https://github.com/nagios-plugins/nagios-plugins/blob/master/plugins-root/check_dhcp.c#L274) and recompile.
- Use the [monitoring-plugins.org](https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/) fork of the Nagios plugins, which has [fixed this issue](https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugins/commit/ba21e26443385dd283d08e0419ff6ff25fedd0e8). [debmon.org](http://debmon.org/packages) has Debian packages available.
- Modify the Nagios command definition to run the plugin through grep, removing the warning. Of course you must now take care to not alter the plugin's exit code, so maybe you want to wrap that up in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/lib/nagios3/plugins/check_dhcp | egrep -v 'run as root|^To |chmod u\+s'
exit "${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

Comment: If only Nagios and its child projects could be relieved of their crappy old development methodologies, this would be pretty trivial to fix in a pull request, checking for the specific capability rather than just root or the setuid flag.

Comment: @peelman sounds like you want https://www.monitoring-plugins.org/

Comment: @peelman in fact, looks like someone [already did it](https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugins/commit/ba21e26443385dd283d08e0419ff6ff25fedd0e8).

Comment: Damn...its too easy to forget that site exists.

Comment: @peelman If only Debian and its child projects could be relieved of their crappy old development methodologies, this would be pretty trivial to fix in a pull request, replacing the crappy nagios-plugins package with a vastly superior fork.

Comment: http://debmon.org/packages

Answer (score 2):

With most of the standard (written in C) plugins, there are alternative (not C) implementations on Nagios Exchange.

For example, [there's a perl check_dhcp](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/DHCP-and-BOOTP/check_dhcp/details) that's really just a wrapper around `dhcping`. Of course, the dhcping binary demands to be run via root/sudo/setuid-root too, but perhaps that binary is less of a security concern for you than the stock check_dhcp plugin.